# nginx map regex to detect old android browsers

Tags: regex, nginx

I have the following map nginx setup:

```
map $http_user_agent $old_browser {
    default 0;
    "~Android [1-2]\." 1;
    "~Mozilla.*Firefox/1[0-9]\." 1;
    "~Chrome/2[0-9]\." 1;
    "~AppleWebKit.*Version/[1-4]\..*Safari" 1;
}
```

I wanted to redirect old Android browsers using this setup, however when testing it on An Android 4.2.2 the $old_browser gets flagged as 1. Why is this?

Here is the full user agent

```
Mozilla/5.0(Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; en-us; SM-T110 Build/JDQ39) 
AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
```

What is wrong with the following regex:

```
"~Android [1-2]\."
```

Why does it match `Android 4.2.2`

Comment: In regex `[1-2]` matches a single character in the range of 1 to 2. It ought not be matching 4.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I actually don't want it to match, but what it does instead is it matches it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches: "~**AppleWebKit**.***Version/[1-4]**..***Safari**" 1;

Mozilla/5.0(Linux; U; Android 4.2.2; en-us; SM-T110 Build/JDQ39) 
**AppleWebKit**/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) **Version/4**.0 Mobile **Safari**/534.30